# HighCharts to 2 or more identical divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, highcharts

I have the following code which only populates 1 of the divs:

```
$(function () {
    var $container = $('.portlet_content_18');

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: $container[0],
            height: 400
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });
});​
```

Where the HTML looks something link this:

```
<div class="portlet_content_18">
<div class="portlet_content_18">
```

How do I get it to populate both divs?  Or all the divs if there are 10, 20, 100 or more identical divs with the same class?

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Chmts/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $.each :

```
$('.portlet_content_18').each(function(){
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: this,
            height: 400
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });
}));
```

Comment: Any chance you could show me that in jsfiddle?  I tried it and it didn't work for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/Chmts/1/